# Installing Ruby via rbenv fails

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

**Problem: I installed ruby, but it is not recognized correctly.**
I'm following the *deploying to VPS*: https://github.com/railscasts/335-deploying-to-a-vps

I am setting my server on ubuntu 12.04 LTS to deploy my rails app. I'm following the railscast on deploying to a VPS, and trying to install ruby through rbenv. It seemed everything was installed correctly, but when I tried to check the ruby version, it gave me errors. The following are the commands that I ran.

```
deployer@max:~$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p125
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sstephenson/ruby-build-download-mirror/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...
Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz...
-> http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sstephenson/ruby-build-download-mirror/e3ea86b9d3fc2d3ec867f66969ae3b92
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p125...
Installed ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125

Downloading rubygems-1.8.23.tar.gz...
-> http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sstephenson/ruby-build-download-mirror/178b0ebae78dbb46963c51ad29bb6bd9
Installing rubygems-1.8.23...
Installed rubygems-1.8.23 to /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125

deployer@max:~$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p125
deployer@max:~$ ruby -v
'ruby' program can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try installing [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use rbenv to install a specific version of Ruby. Instead use [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#readme) to install 1.9.3-p125 into `/usr/local`:

```
ruby-build 1.9.3-p125 /usr/local/
```

Or, install Ruby manually:

```
# Compile Ruby (instead of rbenv)
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev libyaml-dev
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p125/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)";
```

in your shell config

Comment: Did you restart bash by logging out and in again after installing rbenv and ruby?

Comment: Yes. ruby -v still gives me I haven't installed ruby yet, and getting another error. When I do . ~/.bashrc, it says I can't make /root because permission denied

Answer (score 1):

You should restart the shell to allow `rbenv` to find the new Ruby

> $ exec $SHELL
>     $ ruby -v
>
> > ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]